# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 desktop not loading

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, xorg.conf

Relative newbie here. Trying out Ubuntu to hopefully replace my Windows workstation.

Install / partitioning went very smoothly, the problem is trying to get two monitors working.  Each monitor is connected to its own GPU (system has 2 2080RTXs).  Installed the NVIDIA driver, and followed multiple tutorials to get both working, with middling results. Last setup I tried resulted in the desktop not loading after login - resulting in a black screen with a cursor.

Obviously I've screwed something up in the xorg.conf file.  So if anyone can help:

1 - How can I reset the xorg.conf file to a default to hopefully get the desktop back again?
2 - Any recommendations on how to get two monitors - each connected to it's own video card - to work?  This seems much more difficult than I would have expected.  To be clear, I want the desktop to span across the monitors (not mirror).

Thanks for any help!